# Lock direction of UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that I use to pull up a view. the view starts at x = 160, y= 817 and when it is flicked up, I want it to go to 160,284. And When it is flicked back down I want it to automatically go back to the starting point. Here is my code so far:

```
-(IBAction) dragMe: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];

recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, +  recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:recognizer.view.superview];

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:recognizer.view.superview];
    CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.y * velocity.y));
    CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 100;
    NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

    float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
    finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 160), recognizer.view.superview.bounds.size.width);
    finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 284), recognizer.view.superview.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
    } completion:nil];



}
```

}

I don't want the user to be able to move it at all horizontally, just vertically.

Comment: If you're "flicking" and you want it to go to set positions, why aren't you using a swipe gesture recognizer?

Comment: I am trying to imitate to feel of a drawer in a android app...

Comment: If you want to move it only vertically, just eliminate translation.x from where you set recognizer.view.center

Comment: That worked beautifully, I have updated code now. The only issue is that it wont go back all the way down like how it started.